# Error in reorder() function in R ggplot, object not found

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the exact error I am getting -
Error in reorder(Country, Average_literacy_rate, mean) :
object 'Country' not found
In addition: Warning message:
Tried to calculate with group_by(), but the calculation failed.
Falling back to ungrouped filter operation...

The code is below & the 1st chunk i.e. till the summarize function is working fine, so the problem lies in the aes(reorder()) line & being new to R, I can't figure it out. Please help.

```
literacy_data <- read_csv("Literacy rates - Sheet1.csv")

library(stringr)
d <- str_replace(literacy_data$`Literacy rate`, pattern="%", "")
literacy_data$`Literacy rate` <- as.numeric(d)/100

literacy_data %>% 
  filter(Gender=="female") %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  filter(max(Year)==2018 & n_distinct(Year)>=5, mean(literacy_data$'Literacy rate'[Year==2018],na.rm = T)>mean(literacy_data$'Literacy rate'[Year!=2018],na.rm = T)) %>%
  group_by(Country,Year) %>% 
  summarise(Average_literacy_rate = mean(literacy_data$'Literacy rate',na.rm = T), .groups = 'drop')

ggplot(literacy_data,aes(reorder(Country, Average_literacy_rate, mean), Average_literacy_rate, color=as.factor(Year)))+
  geom_point(size=9,alpha=0.4)+
  coord_flip()+
  gghighlight(Year==2018)+
  scale_y_percent()+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("2018"="firebrick"))+
  theme_minimal()+
  labs(x=NULL,y=NULL,title = "Countries that had peak average literacy rate in <span  style='color:firebrick'>**2018**</span>",
  color=NULL)+
  theme_ipsum_ps()+
  theme(plot.title = element_markdown(size=20,margin = margin(b = 10)))
```

*the data set is available at - [dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J__V6ZrMoBq-NC9bVLhCgk-RY6kcKJQPqZrcyFKiKPk/edit?usp=sharing)*

Comment: please check whether "Country" exists

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Your sintax appears wrong...

```
literacy_data <- literacy_data %>%
                 filter(Gender=="female") %>%
```

Remove the `%>%` in the end line summarise....

change :

```
ggplot(aes(reorder(Country, Average_literacy_rate, mean),
        Average_literacy_rate, color=as.factor(Year)))+
        geom_point(size=9,alpha=0.4) ...
```

by

```
 ggplot(literacy_data, aes(reorder(Country, Average_literacy_rate, mean), 
         Average_literacy_rate, color=as.factor(Year)))+
         geom_point(size=9,alpha=0.4)
```

Before the aes you have to inform the dataframe name

Comment: Tried it, it says <error/rlang_error>
Mapping should be created with `aes()` or `aes_()`.

Comment: Can you post your modified code? The above code lacks the "data" object before the aesthetic declaration... I tested it on another base and plotted a graph

Comment: I added the dataframe name and removed the %>% after summarize but it still gives the same error

Comment: It got resolved, i had to use reorder_within and mapping = aes(....